# Grouping a JasperReport based on a variable

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to group data within JasperReports within the report based on calculated data.

I have a set of data that are activities.  Below is a highly simplified setup of the data.  The `Step` is just the order by field (in my actual data, it's a start time).  The `Phase` (simplified here to only 3, but in reality more) indicates whether the activity is a departure (D), enroute (E), or arrival (A).  The `IdealBlock` is what I want to group the activities, but there is no actual field in the database.  As you can see, a departure indicates a new block, and all subsequent rows have that same block number until the next departure (the actual business logic is more complicated).

```
 Step  Phase  IdealBlock
  1      D        1
  2      E        1
  3      E        1
  4      A        1
  5      D        2
  6      E        2
  7      E        2
  8      A        2
```

Since there is no real `IdealBlock` field, I'd like to be able to compute the blocks and have a block footer.  I've made a version of a report that uses `$F{IdealBlock}` for the Group Header's Group Expression and **that looks fine** with the expected 2 groups.

However, my actual data does not have that field.  I've tried to create a "Block" variable to calculate it:

```
Initial Value Expression: 1
Variable Expression: $V{Block} + ("D".equalsIgnoreCase($F{Phase}) ? 1 : 0)
```

Or if you prefer the JRXML:

```
    <variable name="Block" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Block} +
("D".equalsIgnoreCase($F{Phase}) ? 1 : 0)]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
```

When I use `$V{Block}` as the group expression, **each row becomes its own group**.  I would have expected it to work the same (or nearly the same) as when I use `$F{IdealBlock}`.

So I'm wondering:

- Why?  Is this due to some report lifecycle where the Group Expression is calculated at some time other than when I would think?  Or is the result of the Group Expression somehow used differently in the two cases.
- Is there a better way to compute the value on the fly?

Here's the example JRXML file with data included in the SELECT part of the query.  I'm using JasperReports 5.6 and SQL Server 2014, though I also tried it out on JasperReports 6.3 with the same behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestGroupWithVariable" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="765c6d1b-f59c-42c7-93a2-834625a91271">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT 1 as Step, 'D' AS Phase, 1 as IdealBlock
UNION SELECT 2, 'E', 1
UNION SELECT 3, 'E', 1
UNION SELECT 4, 'A', 1
UNION SELECT 5, 'D', 2
UNION SELECT 6, 'E', 2
UNION SELECT 7, 'E', 2
UNION SELECT 8, 'A', 2]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Step" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Phase" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IdealBlock" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="Block" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Block} +
("D".equalsIgnoreCase($F{Phase}) ? 1 : 0)]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Block">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{IdealBlock}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="22">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="451" y="0" width="57" height="20" uuid="f4620cd3-77ee-45e8-ad7e-d171e84b45ad"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Block}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="51" height="20" uuid="452d3259-ce0d-44d7-9b31-744612dc68f4"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Block Var]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="570" height="1" uuid="e220ec89-82c3-40fb-ba74-a5c55987e810"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3036504c-a816-4692-9bda-d4a35ca62d5a"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IdealBlock}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="51" height="20" uuid="a8c7ad92-af7b-4e86-8666-56ca0a91ed71"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Ideal Blk]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="25">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="188" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="7f7ecb95-3178-467c-b13f-058dfcd122fd"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["END BLK " + $V{Block}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="570" height="1" uuid="52270f1e-069c-4684-a546-37acdea2def4"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="40" height="20" uuid="02df6d93-4270-4edd-9540-b48a64173a22"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Phase]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="70" height="20" uuid="12983d11-44af-4d11-9528-f87794056c8c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Phase}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="21" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid="c8ea21cc-b260-4e93-bf1d-3ce293ee63e8"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Step]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="54" height="20" uuid="d8e93236-f7a4-48ed-8174-fe2fcb51bcbc"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Step}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="222" y="0" width="62" height="20" uuid="8edc5a1c-120c-4186-bbe6-f5adfc155209"/>
                <text><![CDATA[IdealBlock]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="284" y="0" width="62" height="20" uuid="d6ef4317-9aa2-449e-bb42-35c30ea80a5f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IdealBlock}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="451" y="2" width="57" height="20" uuid="368be047-58c3-432d-b5bd-ea0653aa5b06"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Block}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="400" y="2" width="51" height="20" uuid="f70c15a3-be06-4205-abe9-a657620ba700"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Block Var]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```